# Razor not rendering view model element correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an input element and the value is coming from my view model

```
<input id="modifyRuleCity" name="City" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value=@Model.City>
```

the value in the viewmodel is "San Francisco", but for some reason the Francisco part is being chopped off. Here is what the rendered HTML looks like.

```
<input id="modifyRuleCity" name="City" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value="San" francisco>
```

I tried

```
value="@Model.City"
```

and

```
value=@Model.City
```

but had no luck it still chops off Francisco.
I looked at the value and I don't see any " in the string in the viewmodel!

Answer (score 3):

As far I Understand:

1. `value = "@Model.City"` should have worked for you unless you don't make mistake another place.
2. If City contains " or ' you can try `value = "@Html.Raw(Model.City)"`
3. If It still it is not working for you, you can try `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "modifyRuleCity", @class = "form-control", Name = "City", PlaceHolder = "City" } })`

Comment: good point to use `@Html.Raw()`. I don't see why that shouldn't work.

Comment: No-go.  Without Html.Raw, the view will encode quotes (&amp;) as HTML entities, like it's supposed to, as well as other characters that need it.

Answer (score 2):

Quotation marks.

```
<input id="modifyRuleCity" name="City" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value="@Model.City">
```

or

```
<input id="modifyRuleCity" name="City" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value='@Model.City'>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using *Razor* then I would suggest to use HTML helpers such as the *EditorFor* and combining that with *lambda expressions* like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "modifyRuleCity", @class = "form-control", @name = "City", @placeholder = "City"} })
```

that will render the same thing as `<input type="text" />`